# Creación de usuario administrador

Tags: php, html, phpmyadmin, xampp, cuenta-usuario

¿Quería preguntar si hay algún tutorial o pagina para realizar la creación de un usuario administrador?

Tengo ya creada una base de datos creada con phpmyadmin (xampp), y una pagina de registro de usuarios con php y html, pero no se como realizar un usuario que pueda ver o eliminar los usuarios creados.

Gracias por las ayudas.

Un saludo a todos.

Comment: edu. Cuáles fueron los querys que ejecutaste? Entiendo que quieres crear un usuario administrador en la base de datos, es así?

Comment: Hola.

Si quiero crear un usaurio administrador en la base de datos, y que luego funcione en le html.

Las query no entiendo creo que no realice ninguna.